# Random between two letters only

Tags: python

**

### Hi everyone, I use to swim around everyday and this is my first time to ask... I wrote this code and dont know how to random M or F for gender output.. here is my code:

**

```
from os import linesep
from random import Random

def generaterandomrecord(firstnamelength, lastnamelength, gender):
    rnd = Random()
    generatedline = ""


    generatedline += chr(rnd.randint(65, 90))
    for index in range(0, firstnamelength):
        randomasciinumber = rnd.randint(97, 122)
        generatedline += chr(randomasciinumber)

    generatedline += " "

    generatedline += chr(rnd.randint(65, 90))
    for index in range(0, lastnamelength):
        randomasciinumber = rnd.randint(97, 122)
        generatedline += chr(randomasciinumber)

    generatedline += ","

    for index in range(0, 10):
        generatedline += str(rnd.randint(0, 10) )

    generatedline += ","

    for index in range(0, gender):
        generatedline += chr(rnd.randint(106, 115))


    return generatedline

filepath = r"t:\test.txt"

filestream = open(filepath, "w")


rnd = Random()
for index in range(0, 300):
    firstnamelength = rnd.randint(3, 5)
    lastnamelength = rnd.randint(5,7 )
    gender = rnd.randint(106, 115)
    filestream.write(generaterandomrecord(firstnamelength, lastnamelength, gender) + linesep)

filestream.flush()

filestream.close()
print("Done processing")
```

thank you

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: \Python27\python.exe T:/session3/Cours/DU/DataGenerator/DataGenerator/Program.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "T:/session3/Cours/DU/DataGenerator/DataGenerator/Program.py", line 43, in <module>
    gender = rnd.randint(106 or 115)
TypeError: randint() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: and this is one ouput line for exemple:                                                   Eczze zttxrj,5109101040903,olnsknprmqlmsmqrrnjkrssnljprsnjkqnmmrjkpplkssomoomkplprrmrspmonnonmnlpqjqrprnojmskmjnpkprpqnsmroprjnrnplqnrmo

Comment: dont post code in the comments (or output unless it is very short and clear)

Comment: I got it finally, I will copy the code in the question for references

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import random
print random.choice("MF")
```

Comment: I did this                                                                                                           for index in range(0, gender):
        generatedline += random.choice("MF")                                                                    and i got this error                                                                                              NameError: name 'random' is not defined

Comment: Did you import random?

Comment: this import is not correct ? (from random import Random) should i import it differently ?

Comment: I got the right thing finally but i dont know how to format a code in a comment..

Comment: this is the solution for who will be intrested                                            {   gendertable = ["M", "F"]
    gendernumber = rnd.randint(0, 1)
    gendertable[gendernumber]

    return generatedline + gendertable[gendernumber]  }

Comment: I wish if i had an optimized solution, but this is what i got it right for instance.. thanks for your assistance

Comment: The optimized solution you're looking for is the one given in this answer which you refuse to use.

Comment: I think you chould change `random.choice` to `rnd.choice` and it will work for you @FrançaisSansFrontières ...